# NotificationCompat Builder displaying notification issue

Tags: android

I want to display notifications from every method in the activity lifecycle on the notification bar

like this

[image]

**Ive edited the code as the example i am following to implement this has issues with GB and below,But the problem is only 1 notification comes up and the previous is replaced
like this**

[image]

**here's the code i am using**

```
package com.qcs.vivek.training_demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    notify("onCreate");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    notify("onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    notify("onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    notify("onStop");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    notify("onDestroy");
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    notify("onRestoreInstanceState");
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    notify("onSaveInstanceState");
}

private void notify(String methodName) {
    String name = this.getClass().getName();
    String strings = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(methodName + " " + strings)
            .setContentText(name);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the `NotificationManager`'s notify method is id of the notification. If you want to show more than one notification all you need to do is instead of always passing 0 as the notification's id use different id for each lifecycle method.